# understanding apply and outer function in R

Tags: r

Suppose i have a data which looks like this

```
ID A B C 
1  X 1 10
1  X 2 10
1  Z 3 15
1  Y 4 12
2  Y 1 15
2  X 2 13
2  X 3 13
2  Y 4 13
3  Y 1 16
3  Y 2 18
3  Y 3 19
3  Y 4 10
```

I Wanted to compare these values with each other so if an ID has changed its value of A variable over a period of B variable(which is from 1 to 4) it goes into data frame K and if it hasn't then it goes to data frame L.

so in this data set K will look like

```
ID A B C 
1  X 1 10
1  X 2 10
1  Z 3 15
1  Y 4 12
2  Y 1 15
2  X 2 13
2  X 3 13
2  Y 4 13
```

and L will look like

```
ID A B C 
3  Y 1 16
3  Y 2 18
3  Y 3 19
3  Y 4 10
```

In terms of nested loops and if then else statement it can be solved like following

```
for ( i in 1:length(ID)){
m=0
for (j in 1: length(B)){
ifelse( A[j] == A[j+1],m,m=m+1)
}
ifelse(m=0,  L=c[,df[i]], K=c[,df[i]])
}
```

I have read in some posts that in R nested loops can be replaced by `apply` and `outer` function. if someone can help me understand how it can be used in such circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you don't need a loop with conditions here, all you need to do is to check if there's a variance (and then converting it to a logical using `!`) in `A` during each cycle of `B` (`ID`s) by converting `A` to a numeric value (I'm assuming its a `factor` in your real data set, if its not a factor, you can use `FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))` within `ave` instead ) and then `split` accordingly. With base R we can use `ave` for such task, for example

```
indx <- !with(df, ave(as.numeric(A), ID , FUN = var))
```

Or (if `A` is a character rather a `factor`)

```
indx <- with(df, ave(A, ID , FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 1L
```

Then simply run `split`

```
split(df, indx)
# $`FALSE`
# ID A B  C
# 1  1 X 1 10
# 2  1 X 2 10
# 3  1 Z 3 15
# 4  1 Y 4 12
# 5  2 Y 1 15
# 6  2 X 2 13
# 7  2 X 3 13
# 8  2 Y 4 13
# 
# $`TRUE`
# ID A B  C
# 9   3 Y 1 16
# 10  3 Y 2 18
# 11  3 Y 3 19
# 12  3 Y 4 10
```

This will return a list with two data frames.

---

Similarly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := !var(A), by = ID]
split(df, df$indx)
```

---

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(indx = !var(A)) %>%
  split(., indx)
```

Comment: sounds simple and powerful, can you please comment on the function you have used that what arguments you have passed and what they do so i can later use it according to my needs. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, didn't I comment enough? Which part you didn't understand?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to understand `apply` rather than simply getting it done, you can consider `tapply`. As a demonstration:

```
> tapply(df$A, df$ID, function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))>1, "K", "L"))
  1   2   3 
"K" "K" "L"
```

In a bit plainer English: go through all `df$A` grouped by `df$ID`, and apply the function on `df$A` within each groupings (i.e. the `x` in the embedded function): if the number of unique values is more than 1, it's "K", otherwise it's "L".

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'ID', we check the `length` of `unique` elements in 'A' (`uniqueN(A)`) is greater than 1 or not, create a column 'ind' based on that.  We can then `split` the dataset based on that 
'ind' column.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, ind:= uniqueN(A)>1, by = ID]
 setDF(df1)
 split(df1[-5],  df1$ind)
#$`FALSE`
#   ID A B  C
#9   3 Y 1 16
#10  3 Y 2 18
#11  3 Y 3 19
#12  3 Y 4 10

#$`TRUE`
#  ID A B  C
#1  1 X 1 10
#2  1 X 2 10
#3  1 Z 3 15
#4  1 Y 4 12
#5  2 Y 1 15
#6  2 X 2 13
#7  2 X 3 13
#8  2 Y 4 13
```

---

Or similarly using `dplyr`, we can use `n_distinct` to create a logical column and then split by that column.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         group_by(ID) %>%
         mutate(ind= n_distinct(A)>1) 
split(df2, df2$ind)
```

---

Or a `base R` option with `table`.  We get the `table` of the first two columns of 'df1' i.e. the 'ID' and 'A'.  By double negating (`!!`) the output, we can get the '0' values convert to 'TRUE' and all other frequency as 'FALSE'.  Get the `rowSums` ('indx').  We match the `ID` column in 'df1' with the `names` of the 'indx', use that to replace the 'ID' with `TRUE/FALSE`, and `split` the dataset with that.

```
 indx <- rowSums(!!table(df1[1:2]))>1
 lst <- split(df1, indx[match(df1$ID, names(indx))])
 lst
#$`FALSE`
#   ID A B  C
#9   3 Y 1 16
#10  3 Y 2 18
#11  3 Y 3 19
#12  3 Y 4 10

#$`TRUE`
#  ID A B  C
#1  1 X 1 10
#2  1 X 2 10
#3  1 Z 3 15
#4  1 Y 4 12
#5  2 Y 1 15
#6  2 X 2 13
#7  2 X 3 13
#8  2 Y 4 13
```

If we need to get individual datasets on the global environment, change the names of the `list` elements to the object names we wanted and use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
list2env(setNames(lst, c('L', 'K')), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```